# What is the equivilant of NSUserDefaults on Windows Phone 7 with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, objective-c, cocoa-touch, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to store small settings related data, like I would with NSUserDefaults on iOS.

What is the equivilant with Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what exacly is NSUserDefaults, but for Windows Phone 7 you can use [ApplicationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Basically, a dictionary that works well for a small set of settings.